# Numpy TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Could someone please explain what the following error is about.  Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
data =pd.read_csv('FILENAME')
b=data.info()
print b
```

Following is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File  
"FILENAME", line 5, in <module>    
    b=data.info()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1443, in  
info  
    counts = self.count()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3862, in  
count  
    result = notnull(frame).sum(axis=axis)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 276, in  
notnull  
    return -res   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 604, in 
__neg__  
arr = operator.neg(_values_from_object(self))
   TypeError: The numpy boolean negative, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the `~`
operator or the logical_not function instead.
```

All I am trying to do is display a summary of my dataset using the `Dataframe.info()` function, and I am having trouble trying to make sense of the error.  Although I do feel it has something to do with the numpy package altogether.  What needs to be done here?

Comment: P.S:I have started coding in python recently, which is why I am still trying to figure all of this out :-)

Comment: Does the file `FILENAME` exist?

Comment: Yes, it does,i just edited that part out, its a valid file

Comment: If you want to display the info just call `data.info()` it won't return anything

Comment: @SreeramTP that doesn't work either, and besides for displaying it I either need to store the same in a variable or directly use the print statement right?

Comment: `data.info()` won't return anything. From pandas documentation : `This method prints information about a DataFrame including the index dtype and column dtypes, non-null values and memory usage.`

Comment: @MVS What is your pandas version.? What is the numpy version.?

Comment: @SreeramTP pandas: 0.13.1,numpy: 1.14.5

Comment: Try updating pandas to a newer version. If you are in conda do `conda update pandas`

Comment: @SreeramTP Ok, will try doing that.

Comment: @SreeramTP it worked, I am able to print the summary of columns for my entire dataset now, Thanks :-)

Comment: @MVS nice to hear it worked. I will post it as answer

Comment: @SreeramTP and you were right, data.info() displays the summarized information without a print statement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the old version of `pandas` as new version of `numpy`.

You must update `pandas` to get your code working.

If you are on `conda` you can do a `conda update pandas` to update `pandas`.

If you are using `pip` you can do  `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Also, keep in mind that in pandas documentation it is mentioned the following for the `info` function

```
This method prints information about a DataFrame including the index dtype and column dtypes, non-null values and memory usage
```

`data.info()` will print the info to the console. So no need to assign it to a variable and then later printing it.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
data =pd.read_csv('FILENAME')
print data.info()
```

This code will work fine for you.